# Agrupar registros, mas mostrar os repetidos em uma linha

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela onde pego todos pedidos realizados no dia, porem mostro todos em uma tabela, ate ai tudo bem, mas o cliente precisa que seja agrupado por quem pediu, vou dar um exemplo,

Na minha tabela tenho

ID_PEDIDO  |  ID_USER_PEDIDO |  PEDIDO

1                   |   20                           |   524

5                   |   52                           |   258

2                   |   35                           |   525

6                   |   52                           |   253

3                   |   20                           |   658

4                   |   20                           |   358

No resultado me aparece conforme consulta e me mostra todos os pedidos em ordem de pedido
**SELECT * FROM pedidos  ORDER BY ID_PEDIDO ASC**

Se eu colocar um GROUP BY ID_USER_PEDIDO vai agrupar os pedidos de acordo com o usuário e mo mostrar apenas 1

Eu preciso que seja mostrado todos eles porem agrupados na mesma linha da tabela

```
 <table id="datatable1" class="table display responsive ">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="">ID</th>
                  <th class="">ID do usuario</th>
                  <th class="">Pedido</th>               
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos  ORDER BY ID_PEDIDO ASC";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);                    
                      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                        
                    
                  ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row["ID_PEDIDO"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["ID_USER_PEDIDO"];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["PEDIDO"];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
               
                      }
                ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Tem alguma forma de aparecer conforme a imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Imagem abaixo?? vejo imagem nenhuma

Comment: Desculpe, a imagem não ter ido, acabei de inserir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "USUARIO";
    $password = "SENHA";
    $db = "NOME_DB";
                
                
    // Criando connexão
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
    // Checando conexão
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
                    
        echo '<table id="datatable1" class="table display responsive" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr><tr><th class="">ID</th><th class="">ID do usuario</th>
              <th class="">Pedido</th></tr>';
              
               /* ######## retorna um valor para cada grupo de registro ID_USER_PEDIDO ######### */
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos GROUP BY ID_USER_PEDIDO ORDER BY ID_USER_PEDIDO ASC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);                    
                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
                                    
                    $meio = $row["ID_USER_PEDIDO"];
              /* ############################################################################### */

                    
              /* #### extrai apenas os registros que atendem a condição ID_USER_PEDIDO = $meio ###### */
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE ID_USER_PEDIDO = $meio ORDER BY ID_PEDIDO ASC";
                    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2); 
                    
                    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
                      $ini .= $row2["ID_PEDIDO"]."<br>";                          
                      $fim .= $row2["PEDIDO"]."<br>";
                    }
              /* ############################################################################### */
                    
                    /* ########### Monta e concatena as linhas da tabela ##################### */
                      $linhas .= ("<tr><td>".$ini."</td><td>".$meio."</td><td>".$fim."</td></tr>");
                    /* ######################################################################### */
                    
                    /* apagando as variaveis */
                    unset($ini);
                    unset($fim);
                    
                    
                    
                } 
                
        /* ##### imprimindo na tela o resultado final ##### */                               
        echo '</thead><tbody>'.$linhas.'</tbody></table>';

           

?>
```

Comment: Valew . obrigado pela ajuda,